# the invoice completed for only one order

Tags: php

i have a problem with the invoice results and my question is if i have multiple orders how do you reset the invoice data ? The results appear only for the first order form the list, it seems like isn't taking the new data from another row. It keeps taking the data from first one...

orders.php - orders list

```html
<?php
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "registration"); 
$sql="SELECT * FROM comenzi";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResults= mysqli_num_rows($result); 

if($queryResults > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
echo "<a href='article1.php?codc=".$row['codc']."&codp=".$row['codp']."'> <table border=1 bgcolor=#b3ccff>
<tr>
    <th>Numar</th>
    <th>Cod produs</th> 
    <th>Cod client</th>
<th>Data </th>
<th colspan=2><center> Actiune </th>
  </tr>

<tr>
    <td><p> ".$row['codc']." </p></td>
    <td><p><a href='produs.php?codc=".$row['codc']."&codp=".$row['codp']."' > ".$row['codp']."</a> </p></td> 
    <td><p><a href='client.php?codc=".$row['codc']."&codcl=".$row['codcl']."' >  " .$row['codcl']."</a> </p></td>
 <td><p> " .$row['datac']." </p></td>
  <td>   </tr> </table>";
}
}
?>
```

article.php - details from one order

```html
<?php

$codc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['codc']); 
$codp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['codp']); 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM comenzi WHERE codc='$codc' AND codp='$codp'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $queryResults=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 

 if($queryResults > 0){
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo "<div class='article-box' > 
   <table border=1 bgcolor=#b3ccff>
<tr>
    <th>Numar </th>
    <th>Cod produs</th> 
    <th>Cod client</th>
<th>Data </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td> <p> ".$row['codc']." </p> 
  </td>
  
  <td> <p> <a href='produs.php?codc=".$row['codc']."&codp=".$row['codp']."' >  ".$row['codp']." </a> </p> 
  </td>
  
  <td> <p><a href='client.php?codc=".$row['codc']."&codcl=".$row['codcl']."' >  ".$row['codcl']." </a></p> 
  </td>
  
  <td> <p> ".$row['datac']." </p> 
  </td> 
  
  </tr> </table> </div>
  
   <form method='post' action='article1.php'> 
     <div class=input-group>
<button type=submit class=btn name=view> <a href='invoice.php?codc=".$row['codc']."&codcl=".$row['codcl']."&codp=".$row['codp']."' style='color: white;' > Vezi factura </a> </button> </div>
     </form>";
  
  
  }
 }
 
 

?>
```

invoice.php -

```html
<?php
include_once 'header.php';


if ( isset($_POST['view'])){
 
  
 $codc = $POST['codc'];
$codp = $POST['codp'];
$codcl = $_POST['codcl'];



$codc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['codc']); 
$codcl = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['codcl']); 
$codp = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['codp']); 

$sql="SELECT seriefc, nrfc, datac, numecl, prenumecl, state, cnp, adresacl, denp, pretp 
FROM facturic 
INNER JOIN comenzi 
ON facturic.codc = comenzi.codc 
INNER JOIN clienti
ON facturic.codcl = clienti.codcl
INNER JOIN produse
ON facturic.codp = produse.codp
WHERE codc='$codc' AND codcl='$codcl' AND codp='$codp'  "; 
 
 
  $res= mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Nu s-a putut completa".mysqli_error($conn));
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
 
 //mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
} 
 
 
 
 ?>
 <table>
 <form method="POST" action="invoice.php">
 <?php 

$result = mysqli_query ( $conn ,"SELECT * FROM facturic ");
$invoice = $result->fetch_assoc (); 
?>

<td ><font size="1" > <b> Seria</b></font> </td>  
<td><font size="1" > <?php echo $invoice['seriefc']; ?> </font> </td> 

<td  ><font size="1"><b>  Nr factura</b></font></td>  
<td><font size="1" ><?php echo $invoice['nrfc']; ?> </font></td> 


<?php $result = mysqli_query ( $conn ,"SELECT * FROM comenzi WHERE codc = '{$invoice['codc']}' " );
$order = $result->fetch_assoc (); 
?>
<td ><font size="1" > <b> Data </b> </font> </td>  
<td><font size="1" ><?php echo $order['datac']; ?></font> </td> 

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  style="border-spacing: 0;"> 
 
 <?php $result = mysqli_query ( $conn ,"SELECT * FROM clienti WHERE codcl = '{$invoice['codcl']}' " );
$client = $result->fetch_assoc (); 
?>
 
<tr> <td > <font size="1" > &emsp;&emsp; <b>Furnizor:</b> S.C. ELECTRONIC WORLD SRL </font></td> 
<td align="right" > <font size="1" > &emsp;&emsp; <b>Cumparator(denumire, forma juridica):</b> <?php echo $client['numecl'].' '.$client['prenumecl']; ?> </font></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> <td > <font size="1" > &emsp; &emsp;<b> Nr. ord.registru com./an:</b> J40/4364/2007</font> </td> 
<td align="right" > <font size="1" > &emsp;&emsp; <b>CNP:</b><?php echo $client['cnp']; ?></font></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> <td> <font size="1" > &emsp; &emsp;<b> C.I.F.:</b> RO 21255775</font> </td>
<td align="right" > <font size="1" > &emsp;&emsp; <b>Adresa:</b><?php echo $client['adresacl'] ;?> </font></td>  
</tr> 
<tr> <td><font size="1" > &emsp; &emsp; <b> Capital social subscris si varsat:</b> 119.000 RON </font> </td>

 </tr> 
<tr> <td><font size="1" > &emsp; &emsp;<b> BRD Sucursala Mari Clienti Corporativi (SMCC)</b></font> </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td><font size="1" > &emsp; &emsp; RO39 BRDE 450S V893 7500 6500</font> </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td><font size="1" > &emsp; &emsp; <b> Sediul:</b> Expozitiei 2,Cladirea MCAR(C9),Sector 1,Bucuresti,012103</font> </td> </tr> 
<tr> <td><font size="1" > &emsp; &emsp;<b> Tel:</b> +40 21 200 52 00, fax: +40 21 200 52 25</font></td> </tr> 
</table>


<br>
<center>
<table  style="width:850px" border="1"> 
<tr> 
<td><center> Nr. crt. </center></td> 
<td><center> Denumirea produsului sau a serviciului</center> </td> 
<td><center> U.M.</center> </td> 
<td> <center> Cota T.V.A.<br> -%- </center></td>
<td><center> Pret unitar <br>  -lei-</center> </td> 
<td><center> Valoarea T.V.A. <br> -lei</center> </td> </tr> 

 <?php 
 
 $result = mysqli_query ( $conn ,"SELECT * FROM produse WHERE codp= '{$invoice['codp']}' " );
$produs = $result->fetch_assoc (); 
?>


<tr> 
<td><center> 1.</center>  </td> 
<td><?php echo $produs['denp']; ?> </td> 
<td><center> buc</center> </td> 
<td><center>19</center> </td> 
<td><center> <?php echo $produs['pretp']; ?></center> </td> 
<td><center><?php echo $produs['pretp']*19/100 ;?></center></td>
</tr>

</center>
</table> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```